# Set of numbers in $\left[0,1\right]$ whose ternary expansion contains only $0$s and $1$s

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set of all numbers in $\left[0,1\right]$ whose ternary (base $3$) expansion includes only $0$s and/or $1$s, but no $2$s. I need to show that $A$ is closed. I noted that the definition is similar to how the Cantor set is defined: the base $3$ expansion includes only $0$s and/or $2$s, but not $1$s. But when I tried to adapt the proof that the Cantor set is closed to this case, I got a bit stuck. Any proof would therefore be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do it directly? For any sequence $a_i$ that converges, once $ |a_n - a_m | < \frac{1}{ 3^k}$, then they will have to agree on the first $k$ (or $k-1$) decimal places in ternary. Hence, the result follows.

Comment: What is $a_i$? The sequence of digits (e.g. $0,1,1,0,1,\dots$)? The sequence of partial sums, i.e. truncations of the number (e.g. $0,0.1,0.11,0.110,0.1101,\dots$)? Or something else?

Comment: The sequence of numbers in $A$ that converge. To show that $A$ is closed, you need to show that any convergent sequence converges in $A$.

Comment: OK, say $a_m = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{m,i}}{3^i}$ and $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{n,i}}{3^i}$. Then for $m,n \geq N$, $\left\lvert a_n - a_m\right\rvert < \frac{1}{3^k}$, so $\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{m,i}-x_{n,i}}{3^i}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{3^k}$. But I'm not sure how you get from that to $x_{m,i}=x_{n,i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ (i.e. "agree on the first $k$ decimal places in ternary"), since $x_{m,i}-x_{n,i}$ can be negative. Could you clarify?

Comment: Let $ A = 0.0\ldots _3 $ and $ B = 0.1\ldots _3$ be any ternary numbers with the given starting digits, and whose expansion only includes 0 or 1s. Then, $ A \leq 0.0111\ldots_3 = \frac{1}{6} < \frac{1}{3} = 0.1_3 \leq B$, or that $ B-A > \frac{1}{6}$. So if $ |a_i - a_j| < \frac{1}{6}$, then their first decimal place agrees. Generalize this.

Comment: If their $k$th decimal place disagrees, the minimum $B-A$ is e.g. $0.d_1d_2\dots d_{k-1}1000\dots - 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{k-1}0111\dots = 0.000\dots1000\dots - 0.000\dots0111\dots$. This evaluates to $3^{-k} - \frac{3^{-(k+1)}}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3^k}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^k} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3^k}$. So if $\left\lvert a_i - a_j\right\rvert < \frac{1}{3^{k+1}}$, then their $k$th decimal place agrees. Is that right?

Comment: (Most likely, but it's late for me and I'm too tired to check arithmetic details. You have the right idea there, just need to verify that everything works out, and use wider bounds as needed.)

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Let $C$ be the Cantor set. Then $A$ is closed iff $C$ is closed because $A=\{x/2: x\in C\}.$